# Regular expression in C/C++

Tags: c++, c, regex, linux, pattern-matching

i have requirement to store the regex in flat file and read them.There will be 1000 regex (i mean 1000 lines with 3 regex pattern each on one line seperated by a delimeter say #).
And the first regex1 is of type hex and other 2 are integers.

FLAT FILE will have

regex1#regex2#regex3

i have now 2 requirement
1)I want throw an error if the regex are not valid.
   This im doing via regcomp function and this basically will check whether it is a proper regex or not(like missing brackets and all).

2)I have one more requirement wherein i need to valid all possible values for the regex which can be derived and throw an error if the operator enters the wrong entry in file.

How can achieve my second goal is my second question

Meaning

say regex1 can be represented in hex but it can be represented in many ways,i knw the length of the regex1,regex2 and regex3.But i want to know whether they are valid regex or not.

basically in short i want to knw is there anything in C regex library which will validate my regex pattern.

Comment: When you want a C library, why is this tagged C++?

Comment: C AND C++ any solution shuld be fine except the boost library

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had great luck with `pcre`. It's lightweight, simple C code which handles regex parsing very well and it's also extremely fast.

Comment: i'm using regcomp function to validate the basic regex and i can use regexec to actually check the pattern matching the request string but i cannot find any function which will tell me whether the pattern itself is valid pattern or not.This is my query

Comment: If `regcomp()` detects an invalid RE, it may return `REG_BADPAT`, or it may return one of the error codes that more precisely describes the error.
http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/regcomp.html

Comment: If that's not what you're looking for, what do you mean by "a valid pattern"?

Comment: a valid pattern meaning i have 3 regex in a file on one line,that will be one for hex and other 2 will be integer.sso valid pattern i want user to enter into a text file valid possible values of regex pattern for hex,int,int appropriately and i want to ensure this programmitcally and display error messages accordingly

Comment: So, what part do you need help with? Or am I supposed to code that for you.

Comment: thanks for the offer.Basically i came to conclusion that we need to write the entire grammar for this requirement and there are no readily available function call like regcomp and regexec ,to check for valid pattern.I was just looking for that answer within this post.I will do the coding further.Thanks..!

Answer (score 1):

I'd use boost::regex for this if you don't mind using an external library.  It has a number of ways to validate regular expressions, and will typically throw you exceptions stating when an expression you're trying to use is invalid.

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_32_0/libs/regex/doc/basic_regex.html

Comment: Thanks for the answer but..i'm forced not to use boost :( due to some constraints

Comment: yes agreed im using that only but i'm using regcomp function to validate the basic regex and i can use regexec to actually check the pattern matching the request string but i cannot find any function which will tell me whether the pattern itself is valid pattern or not.This is my query